# How to encode data loaded with open() into UTF-8?

Tags: python

I have the following script to import a text-based file.

```
with open("test.tsv") as import_lines:
    for line in import_lines:
        line_parsed = line.strip().split("\t")
        print(line_parsed[0])
```

The output of this file is something like this:

```
2006\u5E74\u5B66\u672F\u6587\u7AE0
2006\u5E74\u5B78\u8853\u6587\u7AE0
2006\u5E74\u5B78\u8853\u6587\u7AE0
```

I assumed that decoding was as simple as:

```
print(line_parsed[0].encode().decode("utf-8"))
```

But this results in the exact same result.

I did notice that:

```
print(line_parsed[0].encode())
```

results in:

```
b'2006\\u5E74\\u5B66\\u672F\\u6587\\u7AE0'
b'2006\\u5E74\\u5B78\\u8853\\u6587\\u7AE0'
b'2006\\u5E74\\u5B78\\u8853\\u6587\\u7AE0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `encode().decode()`, open your file in binary mode:

```
with open("test.tsv", "rb") as import_lines:
    for line in import_lines:
        line_parsed = line.strip().decode('unicode-escape').split("\t")
        print(line_parsed[0])
```

Output:

```
2006年学术文章
2006年學術文章
2006年學術文章
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(line_obj["label"].encode().decode("unicode-escape"))
```

Comment: Too late... My answer: `open('test.tsv', 'rb').read().decode('unicode-escape')`